# Creating a Folder using Program

Tags: android, implementation

I want to create a directory by using program in android sdk. Is it possible to listen the folder action like open folder and close folder etc.

Please help me to do this?

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating folder in your SDK, create it in your android SDcard.
You can create your files and folders as per your requirement.
Go through this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)